# What is the 'migration" process?

Tags: linux

I see lots of those on my production server, they come and go and take up lots of CPU time

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
   17 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S 1661  0.0   4728:03 migration/3
   29 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S 1508  0.0   4728:03 migration/6
```

Answer (score 56):

The migration kernel process distributes workload across CPU cores. You should have one migration process per processor core.

Answer (score 2):

"migration" is a kernel process

Check [here](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/issues/28)

Comment: Down-voted for providing a link with no summary of what said process is.  Up-voted the Answer which doesn't merely link, and actually explains the answer.

Comment: Upvoted to counter silly downvote.

Comment: Downvoted to counter silly upvote. The link is just a link to someone's github account. Providing it with no summary is just begging for the explanation to get deleted and make the answer useless in the future.

Comment: Down voted as not an answer, just a link.